# Python function that similar to bash find command

Tags: python

I have a dir structure like the following:

```
[me@mypc]$ tree .
.
├── set01
│   ├── 01
│   │   ├── p1-001a.png
│   │   ├── p1-001b.png
│   │   ├── p1-001c.png
│   │   ├── p1-001d.png
│   │   └── p1-001e.png
│   ├── 02
│   │   ├── p2-001a.png
│   │   ├── p2-001b.png
│   │   ├── p2-001c.png
│   │   ├── p2-001d.png
│   │   └── p2-001e.png
```

I would like to write a python script to rename all *a.png to 01.png, *b.png to 02.png, and so on. Frist I guess I have to use something similar to `find . -name '*.png'`, and the most similar thing I found in python was `os.walk`. However, in `os.walk` I have to check every file, if it's png, then I'll concatenate it with it's root, somehow not that elegant. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a search pattern like that, you can probably get away with [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

```
from glob import glob
paths = glob('set01/*/*.png')
```

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with the recursive glob provided by pathlib:

```
import pathlib
for p in pathlib.Path(".").rglob("*.png"):
    print(p)
```

The package provides useful features for renaming files, too.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem

---

For Python 2 [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) could be used to traverse the directory tree.

Example:

```
import os

for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("."):
  for i, fname in enumerate([os.path.join(dpath, fname) for fname in fnames]):
    if fname.endswith(".png"):
      #os.rename(fname, os.path.join(dpath, "%04d.png" % i))
      print "mv %s %s" % (fname, os.path.join(dpath, "%04d.png" % i))
```

Comment: I would consider using `if file.endswith(".png"):` instead of that `rsplit()` (which will do more work than is really necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [genfind.py](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html) from David M. Beazley.

```
# genfind.py
#
# A function that generates files that match a given filename pattern

import os
import fnmatch

def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

# Example use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lognames = gen_find("access-log*","www")
    for name in lognames:
        print name
```

Answer (score -2):

These days, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a convenient option.