# if file don't exist using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

Is there an easy way to check that a file exists in the entire folder structure without having to cycle? (the use of `os.walk` is necessary)

```
"if file exist in in my_dir and its sub directories"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_dir):
       # do stuff
else:
    print("file does not exist")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function that similar to bash find command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247157/python-function-that-similar-to-bash-find-command)

Comment: use `break` and unindent your `else` block.

Comment: the intent is to first check globally if the file exists, if it exists then start cycling through the folders in search of it, otherwise do other stuff

Comment: So, the file can exist in a directory or any of its subdirectories? In that case you can't avoid having to recursively search through your directories to find the file.

Comment: so I can't check if the file is in that directory or any of its subdirectories without using a cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob.glob` as follows:

```
import glob

fname = 'some_file.txt'
my_dir = '/some_dir' # can also be a relative path
files = glob.glob(f'{my_dir}/**/{fname}', recursive=True)
if files: # list of files that match
    # do something
```

`glob.glob` will now look for file `some_file.txt` in directory `my_dir` or any of its subdirectories.

Comment: it works fine, I can incorporate this code into a method and avoid having nested loops, thanks a lot!